# Rail Application Model/Controller & Routrs organisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controllers

I'm trying to work on this Rails app which has the following objectives:

`/foods/` - render a list of food categories (eg: Breads, Dairy, Biscuits...etc)
`/foods/breads/` - render all Foods that are within the food category "Breads"
`foods/breads/bagel` - render a detailed view of the properties of the Food (in this example a Bagel).

Currently I have two models with associated controllers:

`Foods` - contains a list of foods (eg: bagel, rice, toast, rich tea biscuit...etc) and is set up to `belongs_to` a single Food Cat

`Food Categories` - a list of categories such as "Dairy", "Breads"...etc & is set up to `has_many :foods`

I'm really stuck on how to achieve my objectives. I really need advice on routing, controller actions and views.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should learn basics (on railsforzombies.org for instance), then create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes.rb file, I would do the following:

```
match 'foods' => 'FoodCategories#index'
match 'foods/:category' => 'Foods#index'
match 'foods/:category/:name' => 'Foods#show'
```

I would then create a scope for Foods by category:

```
class Food
  scope :by_category, lambda{ |category| joins(:categories).where('categories.name = ?', category) }
end
```

I would then have 2 actions in your FoodsController:

```
class FoodsController
  def index
    @foods = Food.by_category(params[:category])
  end

  def show
    @foods = Food.by_category(params[:category]).where('foods.name = ?', params[:name])
  end
end
```

And a single action in your FoodCategoriesController:

```
class FoodCategories
  def index
    @categories = Category.where(name: params[:category])
  end
end
```

That should leave you with having to implement 3 views: categories/index, foods/index and foods/show.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a *FoodsController* and a *FoodCategoriesController* dealing with *Food* and *FoodCategory* models.
if you follow the RESTful approache, then the routes neccessary to achieve the url configuration you listed will be as follows:

```
match '/foods' => 'food_categories#index'
match '/foods/:category_id' => 'food_categories#show'
match '/foods/:category_id/:food_id' => 'foods#show'
```

Your *FoodCategoriesController* will have methods **index** method which lists all the categories by performing *FoodCategory.find :all* lookup, as well as **show** method which will lookup a *FoodCategory* based on provided `:category_id` and display all the foods associated with it via has_many relationship.
Your *FoodController* will have a **show** method that will at least take the `:food_id` and look up the Food instance associated with it. `:category_id`  is not really neccessary here, but its a nice routing sugar.

Comment: Wow these answers both look fantastic. I will review in-depth tomorrow and implement. You are both lifesavers!

Comment: Can anyone explain why  

link_to food_category.name, foods_path(food_category)  

Produces:

http://localhost:3000/foods.983340129

Comment: it all depends on how your foods route is defined.

Comment: match '/foods/' => 'food_categories#index', :as => :foods  

This really makes no sense to me. I've read around and I was sure I was doing it right.

Comment: Ok I managed to get part of this working by naming my route thus  

  match '/foods' => 'food_categories#index', :as => :categorys_list   
  match '/foods/:food_category_id' => 'food_categories#show', :as => :foods_list  
  match '/foods/:food_category_id/:food_id' => 'foods#show', :as => :foods_detail